# Pandora pauses randomly?

Tags: pandora

I find that Pandora often will pause the current song for no apparent reason. Any idea what I might check to see what the cause is?

(HTC Droid Incredible)

Comment: Are you listening with headphones?

Comment: Not using headphones.

Comment: I think it's a bug with their Android client. I have the same problem -- it even happens on my home WiFi!  When I use my desktop or laptop systems (website or AIR app) it's fine.

Comment: I've had this happen with every audio app I've tried on Android (not just Pandora, but Music and Listen as well).  I opened a bug for it: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19167

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a full signal. Try running it with nothing else running. The resources might be getting used by another app and makes pandora freak out. I know on my droid x2 i have a problem with it skipping songs on me.

Comment: How do you make sure you have a full data signal? It's either on or off with my phone.

Comment: I meant go to a location near you that you know you can get full bars. I noticed that when I am around grand central station in NYC that pandora freaks out because of the signal. Just a thought.

Comment: I have similar issues and I'm less than a block away from a Verizon store. I'm assuming they have decent coverage at their own store?

Comment: @Joe: They don't *need* to, a store could simply use femtocells to make sure that the signal is very strong in their store and able to handle the load of a concentration of phones (for both display models and customer's phones).  It'd be a pretty underhanded thing for them to do if the area's signal was otherwise poor though.

Answer (score 1):

I was (still am?) having a similar issue. Pandora will load but not play songs. Or sometimes if it does manage to load and play a song, it will skip to the next song prematurely. I 'restarted' the phone and that didn't fix the issue. I should have shut it down completely and then tried again as a test but instead I reseated the SD card securely after shutting down and it seems to have fixed it. So my solution that worked was either shutting down completely or else reseating the card. We'll see how long it lasts.

Update: Today (the next day) my phone is having issues again. Going into `Task Manager > Ram > Clear memory` seems to have fixed it this time although I don't think it fixed it yesterday. Very peculiar problem.

It seems that my problem might be different than yours but I found that having Twitter installed can cause problems with YouTube, Pandora, etc. I uninstalled and it seems to be helping with my specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are using a battery saver app. I use Juice Defender and I think that's causing the issue. Juice Defender tries to save battery by killing the 3g signal after you turn off the screen for a bit. So you can just deactivate it when you are using pandora.

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on my dinc a while ago. At least for me, I narrowed it down to song buffering. When just about anything happened that changed my data connectivity (received SMS, briefly lost 3G signal) Pandora wouldn't be able to keep up; the song I was listening to would play through as much of it as Pandora had buffered before the network interruption then would stop abruptly and switch to a new song. Very annoying! Even when my data connection was strong, as you mention yours was, Pandora was very picky.

Since that time my listening habits have changed but I've also found Pandora to be more stable over the intervening updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I just figured out what was causing it on my system.  It turns out that I was using **yahoo mail client** on my android phone and everytime I got an email, pandora would pause for a second.  It does not appear that there is a way to change the frequency with which the yahoo client checks email from continuous to some lesser frequency (such as every two hours).  This, unfortunately leaves me with the difficult choice between yahoo mail and pandora.  Pandora will win this battle for sure.

Answer (score -3):

While solid coverage is definitely required for solid playback from Pandora, assuming that is the case (and it's not caused by the way Pandora inserts advertisements), the pauses are most likely related to a low memory condition as a result of memory leaks caused by applications that address contexts in a certain manner.  In other words, it's a flaw in the Android OS that even allows this to be an issue, IMO.

While you could remove the offending apps (if you knew which ones they were), another way this can be dealt with is by getting a task killer that automatically closes unused apps.

Then again, you could load another ROM, doing away with the bloated default apps from the telco and solve the remaining problems with scripts or a task-killer of your own.